# Multiple Ajax call with same JSON data key calling one php file

Tags: php, ajax, validation

I am trying to validate list of dynamic text fields.
Validation needs an AJAX call to interact with server.
At the backend I have written just one php file that reads the input request data and performs operation. Below is the example.

abc.js

```
row_count = 6
for (i = 1; i <=row_count; i++) {
    id = "#val"+i.toString() ;
    $(id).change(function(){
        input_val="random";
        $.ajax({
            url:"url.php",
            type:post,   
            async:true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data : {temp:input_val},
            success:function(result){},
            error: function (request, status, error) {}
        });
    });
}
```

url.php

```
<?php
$random_val = $_POST['temp'];
$cmd = 'systemcommand '.$random_val;
$flag = exec($cmd);
if ($flag == 0){
    echo json_encode(array("status"=>'Fail'));
}
else{
    echo json_encode(array("status"=>'Success'));
}
?>
```

It works fine when the row_count = 1 (Just one text field) but fails when the input is more than 1.
When the count is more than 1, the php script is not able to read the request data(The key in JSON data "temp"). it is blank in that case.
Any lead or help should be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You dont need to make a whole block of js code for each change event handler that is the same. Just attach it to a `.class` selector instead of `#id` selector.

Comment: I don't know what the real value of `input_val` is, but as you don't define it using `var`, it is probably global so it might not be what you think it is after the loop has finished. Is this the exact code you are using? If not, you should post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript bit needs some adjusting, because you do not need to define an ajax for every single element. Use events based on a class. Also, since `input` behave differently than `select`, you should setup two different event class handlers.

```
function validateAjax ( element ) {
    var input_val = element.val();// get the value of the element firing this off
    $.ajax({
        url: "url.php",
        type: 'post',   
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        data : { temp: input_val },
        success: function(result) {
            // check your result.status here
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) { }
    });
}
$(".validate_change").on("change",function() { // for selects
    validateAjax( $(this) );
});
$(".validate_input").on("input",function() { // for text inputs
    validateAjax( $(this) );
});
```

And for your `select` or `input` you add that appropriate class.

```
<select class="validate_change" name="whatever"><options/></select>
<input class="validate_input" name="blah">
```

**PS**

I really worry about this code you have:

```
$cmd = 'systemcommand '.$random_val;
$flag = exec($cmd);
```

So, you are just executing anything that is coming in from a webpage POST var??? Please say this website will be under trusted high security access, and only people using it are trusted authenticated users :-)

Comment: Yes only authenticated users can access this page. Thanks. It works